# Golang - DumpRequest() not creating correct output for ReadRequest()?

Tags: go

Creating a byte array of a http request and then trying to read it into a http.request doesn't seem to work when the request includes a body.

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/Bar", strings.NewReader("Foo"))
rReq, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)

req2, _ := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(rReq)))
b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req2.Body)
fmt.Println(b)
```

b is an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

Two things are wrong in your code:

1. You must handle the errors. This would have helpesd you see that you never construct a valid request ("/Bar" is not a valid URL).
2. Use `httputil.DumpRequestOut` for outgoing request.

Takeaways: **Always** handle all errors and always read the whole **whole** package doc.

Comment: Is there no way to use these methods for 'invalid' URLS? Long explanation buy mt URL has to be "/Foo/Bar" format.

Comment: I just replaced all "_"-s with err and `if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 }` and none of them returned an error.

Comment: How could a HTTP request to an invalid URL succeed? Which host to contact when none is in the URL? So No.

Comment: `http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/Bar", strings.NewReader("Foo"))` fails.